# How to get data from database with condition on another table where something exist or not

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table for `users` like this

```
id   |   name    |     password     |      email
1        saeid         *****              asd@asd.com
```

I have another table called `appointments`

```
id   |   created_by    |     due_date     |     notification_send
1              1              *****                    0
```

I want to get all users from `users` table where they have **at least created one appointment** in the `appointments` table (denoted by `created_by` field in the appointments table).

I have tried  the code below but it fails:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN appointments a ON persons.id = a.created_by
```

But obviously it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `exists` predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM appointments a WHERE a.created_by = u.id)
```

Alternatively you could use an `inner join`, but the `exists` query corresponds better to your question in my opinion (that is if you only need data from the `users` table).

The `left join` says to get all rows from `users` regardless if they have matching rows in `appointments` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a match between the table and so I would suggest doing a `INNER JOIN` rather like below

```
SELECT * FROM users u
JOIN appointments a ON u.id = a.created_by
```

Also check your `ON` clause once I think either this is a typo or a big mistake. You are selecting from `users` table then why `persons.id`??

```
ON persons.id = a.created_by
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eba3/2

```
    select * from users c where (select count(*) from appointments where created_by = c.id) > 0;
```